# Is DC Comics Detective Comics Comics?

Tags: dc, names

DC, at least originally, stood for "Detective Comics."

[image]

Therefore, due to [RAS Syndrome](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RAS_syndrome), DC Comics would technically be "Detective Comics Comics."

Is this true? Or did they officially change the name so that DC either stood for something else or nothing at all?

If it's still officially Detective Comics Comics, have any of the company's higher-ups commented on this?

Comment: Try saying the title three times fast.

Comment: By figuring that out, does that make you a detective?

Comment: @JohnSensebe It would make me a Detective Comics Comics comics detective.

Comment: This is an extremely reductive view of the name. With a bit of history amply covered by Wikipedia, you will learn the company name was a branding element created specifically to create a company to sell comics under. It would later change and become National Comics Publications in 1946. Due to branding concerns, they became better known as Superman-DC (due to the Man of Steel's meteroric fame at the time). They wouldn't become officially known as DC Comics until 1977. Consider DC Comics as a company name and Detective Comics as a brand/product name. Such silly reductive logic is unnecessary.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

### **YES**, but not like it sounds.

---

A convincing argument from  [Reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/DCcomics/comments/1x3oq8/does_it_bother_anyone_else_that_the_c_in_dc/cf81a78):

> DC has become the name of the company, so Detective Comics is the full name. Detective Comics comics is not really redundant.
>
> Detective Comics (brand) comics (product)

A secondary comment goes on to mention that DC Comics is just the publishing arm of the main company, DC Entertainment.

Interestingly, *Detective Comics* is actually the third name of the comic company, after *New Fun: The Big Comic Magazine* and *Adventure Comics*, respectively ([citation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DC_Comics#CITEREFJones2004)).

Comment: They were AC before becoming DC? Shocking.